# Is it possible to translate function, methods, etc. in Python?

Tags: python, localization, internationalization, gettext

I know how to have Python localize output of functions, at least anything involving strings.  Lots of good questions here about that.   I want to do something possible more stupid, but also more basic.

Realistically, it is a handicap that most (popular?) languages are in English of one kind or another.  Okay, we deal with that.  But what about when creating my *own* stuff?

```
class Tomato:
    def __init__(self,color):
        self.color = color
```

Happily I can then do

```
> T = Tomato('red')
> T.color
'red'
```

Suppose I want to localize not the color name, but *the word `color` itself* - or `Tomato`.  So that someone else could do, e.g. in German

```
> T = Tomate('rot')
> T.farbe
'rot'
```

without having to know English, or for me to have to write some app interface that exposes only strings to the user.

How the heck would one wrap the original stuff in gettext or friends to do *that*?  Is it even possible?  I am assuming the answer is no, or I would have found it.  But ... is there any language that would support this kind of thing?  It would seem very useful.  (Please don't troll me if this is a dumb question, instead please explain why this sort of thing doesn't seem to be even on the radar screen.)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, dunno how dynamic you could make this, but here's a look:

The weird type() behavior is inspired by

http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/28/improve-your-python-metaclasses-and-dynamic-classes-with-type/

```
class Tomato(object):
    def __init__(self,color):
        self.color = color
T = Tomato('red')
T.color


di_trad = {"Tomato": "Tomate"}

def xlator(self, attrname):
    di = {"farbe":"color"}
    attr_eng = di.get(attrname,attrname)
    return getattr(self, attr_eng)
```

this works... but only because Tomate is hardcoded...  You wouldn't want to do this, but it is shows you the basic idea.

```
Tomate = type("Tomate",(Tomato,),dict(__getattr__=xlator))
t = Tomate('rot')
print t.farbe

#to me this is the weak point ... emitting arbitrary dynamic classnames
#into the current module.  mind you, we really want to do this against 
#say an import german module...
# and we want to allow drive which classes we translate dynamically as well
```

Same dynamic generation below, but nothing is harcoded about Tomato or Tomate here.  Same idea as above, but you drive the translation by looping through a dict and assigning to a translation support module.

```
di_class_trad = {"Tomato" :"Tomate"}

import german
for engname, tradname in di_class_trad.items():
    cls_ = globals().get(engname)
    setattr(german, tradname, type(tradname,(cls_,),dict(__getattr__=xlator)))
    #in any case

t2 = german.Tomate("blau")
print t2.farbe
```

which outputs:

> rot
>   blau

BTW, the contents of the german.py above are just:

```
pass
```

Note that the translation routines are driven by dictionaries so in theory it is pretty dynamic.

I would keep all the attributes in one dictionary, not a per-class dictionary.  Then, as you go through farbe/color, height/höhe, width/breite translation pairs, you'd want to check that the translated class (Tomato) had that property (width) before assigning its translation, breite, to class Tomate.

Regarding dynamic properties, this is a tweak of what Sublime Text generates as a property skeleton.  If you drove it with a loop for the xlator dictionary and assigned the property to the target class, who knows, it might work...

```
def farbe():
    doc = "The farbe property."
    def fget(self):
        return self.color
    def fset(self, value):
        self.color = value
    def fdel(self):
        del self.color
    return locals()


#farbe = property(**farbe())
#would this work?
setattr(tgt_class,"farbe", property(**farbe()))
```

Cute, but again, not sure how much real use this would be, unless you keep the actual user-visible translated capabilities to pretty basic manipulation.  It might help to assign Tomate a second ancestor class in the type call to add some brains to keep sanity.

i.e.

```
 setattr(german, tradname, type(tradname,(cls_,SanityManagerClass),dict(__getattr__=xlator))
```

Comment: amusing?  Yes.  practical.  Glaube Ich nicht.

Comment: Very interesting (the second way), thanks.  Do you think it would be possible to do *without* both the `german` module *and* hardcoding?  I assume not.

Comment: I don't know how to set new classes into the current module's namespace and I think using a language module is cleaner.  Re. hardcoding, if you disregard the first exploratory part where Tomate is set directly, there is actually limited harcoding - things are driven by the 2 dictionaries.  The real shortcomings in my opinion are:  Tomate's farb is not discoverable via dir(Tomate) (maybe generating properties dynamically would do it), there is a risk that a translation masks the original class/attribute names and the support is limited to getting attributes (again properties could help).

Comment: keep in mind.  "import german" can also be replaced by a dynamic module loader.  i.e. tgt_module = import_translation("german").  Turtles all the way down.